# Xamarin audioplayer menu always on top and expand

Tags: c#, xamarin, menu, audio-player, always-on-top

I'm creating an app for android and ios to listen to music from my radio station. For now I have a tabbedPage design with the menu option at the bottom. In the MainActivity I have created a ContentView with a linearLayout that always stays on top of all tabpages.
But I would like that the player can be expanded to the top and reverse.

I have made a video screenshot of another app from the netherlands of what I would like to achieve.
[image]

Biggest question, is the TabbedPage capable to do this or do I need a whole other setup?

Different kinds of linearLayouts or relativeLayouts

Added code by request of ToolmakerSteve.
In my MainActivity OnCreate I have this:

```
ViewGroup contentView = FindViewById<ViewGroup>(Android.Resource.Id.Content);
                LinearLayout view = new LinearLayout(this);
                view.Orientation = Android.Widget.Orientation.Horizontal;
                view.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Blue);
                view.Background = getDrawableWithRadius();
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams parameter = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams((Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Tablet ? 60 : LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent), (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Tablet ? 110 : 160));
                parameter.Gravity = GravityFlags.Bottom | GravityFlags.Left;
                parameter.BottomMargin = 220;
                view.LayoutParameters = parameter;

                btnPushPlay = new Android.Widget.ImageButton(this);
                btnPushPlay.Click += BtnPushPlay_Click;
   btnPushPlay.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
                btnPushPlay.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.media_play_green);
                view.AddView(btnPushPlay);
                lblSong = new TextView(this);
                lblSong.TextSize = 18;
                lblSong.SetPadding(10, 35, 0, 0);
                lblSong.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.White);
                lblSong.Text = "Luister live!";
                view.AddView(lblSong);
                contentView.AddView(view);
```

And in the MainPage.xaml I have this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Kickit_Radio.MenuPages;assembly=Kickit_Radio"
            xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:local1="clr-namespace:Kickit_Radio.ViewModels"
            android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"
            BarBackgroundColor="#000000"
            BarTextColor="White"
            BackgroundColor="Black"
            x:Class="Kickit_Radio.MainPage"
            NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
            NavigationPage.HasBackButton="True" SelectedTabColor="Green" UnselectedTabColor="#3184ca">
    <TabbedPage.Children>
        <local:Home Title="Home" IconImageSource="home.ico" />
        <local:Nieuws Title="Nieuws" IconImageSource="@drawable/news" />
        <local:Request Title="Request" IconImageSource="@drawable/record" />
        <local:Programma Title="Programma" IconImageSource="@drawable/column" />
        <local:Streams Title="Streams" IconImageSource="@drawable/record" />
        <local:Contact Title="Contact" IconImageSource="@drawable/about"/>
    </TabbedPage.Children>
</TabbedPage>
```

Comment: Add to question the relevant code that you have now (even though it does not do what you want). This makes it easier for people to know exactly what you have, and to suggest a code change.

Comment: This is Xamarin.Android not Xamarin.Forms, right?

Comment: Hey @ToolmakerSteve I have added the code and xaml which I am currently using..
I have the code in the OnCreate from someone else a few years ago. So far it works but I would like it to behave similar like on the gif I added. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm. `ViewGroup contentView = FindViewById` is a native Android view (Xamarin.Android). `MainPage.xaml` with `<TabbedPage` is cross-platform (Xamarin.Forms). I'm vague on how those combine. In a Xamarin.Forms app, I guess that `<ViewGroup>(Android.Resource.Id.Content)` is the Android main activity's content, that Xamarin.Forms manipulates. Then `contentView.AddView(view)` adds the native Android mediaplayer on top of that (child drawing order).

Comment: Yes indeed. The `ViewGroup` is in the main activity of the android class. That's why I want to change the view with some kind of `Layout` or `View` so it also works with ios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching and thinking, I came up with a solution to add a page to the `TabViewItem`.
First, you need to edit your `xaml`-file from `ContentPage` to `ContentView`.
Also change the `BindingContext` and the `Content`, for example:

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:Your_application.ViewModels"
    x:Class="Your_application.MenuPages.MenuName">
<ContentView.BindingContext>
    <viewModels:MenuNameModel />
</ContentView.BindingContext>
    <ContentView.Content>
        ....
    </ContentView.Content>
</Content>
```

Also change your class:

```
public partial class MenuName : ContentPage
```

To:

```
public partial class MenuName : ContentView
```

After that, you can add your page to the `TabViewItem`

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:tool="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
        x:Class="Your_application.MainPage"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Your_application.ViewModels;assembly=Kickit_Radio"
         xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Your_application.MenuPages;assembly=Kickit_Radio">
<Grid x:Name="tabView">
    <tool:TabView TabStripPlacement="Bottom"
        TabStripBackgroundColor="Black"
        TabStripHeight="60"
        TabIndicatorColor="#3184ca" x:Name="myTabView">
        <tool:TabViewItem
             Icon="home.ico"
             Text="Home"
             TextColor="White"
             TextColorSelected="Green"
             FontSize="12"
             x:Name="tb1">
             <Grid BackgroundColor="Black">
                 <local:HomeView />
             </Grid>
         </tool:TabViewItem>
    </tool:TabView>
</Grid>
</ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Hope this will help you further!

Answer (score 1):

Two techniques.

---

**#1: Android code that toggles native media player between two views**

MainActivity.cs:

```cs
// This must be a member of the app class, so it exists after OnCreate finishes.
LinearLayout view;   // small view
ViewGroup bigView;   // large view

... OnCreate()
{
    
    // Change this:
    //LinearLayout view = new LinearLayout(this);
    // To this:
    view = new LinearLayout(this);
    ...
    btnPushPlay = new Android.Widget.ImageButton(this);
    ...
    contentView.AddView(view);

    // Using Android XML layout (".xml" resource file, not XAML), define an Android view that contains native Android MediaPlayer.
    bigView = ...;
    // TODO: set Gravity to Top.
    ...
    // TBD: I think we can add it now, but either ".Gone" or ".Invisible".
    bigView.Visibility = Android.Views.ViewStates.Gone;   // Not there at first.
    contentView.AddView(bigView);   // Or maybe do this later, when want it.
}

private void ToggleMediaPlayer(bool large)
{
    if (large)
    {
        view.Visibility = Android.Views.ViewStates.Gone;
        bigView.Visibility = Android.Views.ViewStates.Visible;
    }
    else
    {
        view.Visibility = Android.Views.ViewStates.Visible;
        bigView.Visibility = Android.Views.ViewStates.Gone;
    }
}

// TODO: btnPushPlay needs a click method that calls `ToggleMediaPlayer(true);`.
// TODO: bigView must have a button that calls `ToggleMediaPlayer(false);`.
```

---

**#2: Do it all in Xamarin.Forms**

- Remove the code in OnCreate, that creates and adds `view` to the content.
- Instead of TabbedPage, use [Community Toolkit / TabView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/tabview).
- Use an XF Grid to overlay the small and large views, on top of the page that has TabView.

MainPage.xaml:

```xml
<!-- change from TabbedPage to ContentPage -->
<ContentPage ...>
  <!-- outer grid, with three overlaid children. -->
  <Grid RowDefinitions="*" ...>

    <!-- replacement for TabbedPage -->
    <!-- https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/blob/main/samples/XCT.Sample/Pages/Views/TabView/CustomTabsPage.xaml -->
    <Grid x:Name="tabview" ...>
      <TabView ...>
        ...
      </TabView>
    </Grid>

    <!-- small view overlay -->
    <!-- TODO: OR maybe this should become a new row in "tabview" Grid above. -->
    <Grid x:Name="smallView" RowDefinitions="*,Auto" ...>
        <!-- nothing in Row 0: it is empty space -->

        <!-- small view at bottom of screen -->
        <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" ...>
            ...
            <ImageButton x:Name="btnPushPlay" .../>
            ...
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>

    <!-- large view overlay -->
    <Grid x:Name="bigView" IsVisible="False" ...>
        ...
    </Grid>

  </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

In MainPage.xaml.cs:

```cs
// Change from ": TabbedPage" to "ContentPage".
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{

  private void ToggleMediaPlayer(bool large)
  {
    bigView.IsVisible = large;

    // This probably isn't needed, if bigView covers the entire screen.
    //MAYBE smallView.IsVisible = !large;
  }

// TODO: btnPushPlay needs a click method that calls `ToggleMediaPlayer(true);`.
// TODO: bigView must have a button that calls `ToggleMediaPlayer(false);`.
```

You'll have to research, to fill in missing details. And tweak according to your needs.

Comment: Great! That helps me a lot
As I see I have lot's of work now ;)

Comment: How about adding pages to the content of the `TabViewItem`?